# Appending svg into a background-image

Tags: javascript, css, svg, d3.js

How do I assign a dynamically generated svg to the background image of div?

I use d3 to generate a word cloud. This appends an svg tag to a `<div>`

```
 d3.select("#_wordcloud_element").append("svg")
                        .attr("width", scope.width )
                        .attr("height", scope.height)
                        .append("g")
                        .attr("transform", "translate("+scope.width/2+","+scope.height/2+")")
                        .selectAll("text")
                        .data(words)
                        .enter().append("text")
                        .style("font-size", function (d) {
                            return d.size + "px";
                        })
                        .style("font-family", "Arial")
                        .style("fill", function (d, i) {
                            return fill(i);
                        })
                        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                        .attr("transform", function (d) {
                            return "translate(" + [d.x, d.y] + ")rotate(" + d.rotate + ")";
                        })
                        .text(function (d) {
                            return d.text;
                        });
```

Instead of appending svg to the div, I want the svg to be the background image of the . I'm blanking on how to do this.

EDIT

Example SVG output from my function:

```
svg width="500" height="400"><g transform="translate(250,200)"><text text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(22,-70)rotate(90)" style="font-size: 42px; font-family: Arial; fill: rgb(31, 119, 180);">Environment</text><text text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(-73,-27)rotate(90)" style="font-size: 37px; font-family: Arial; fill: rgb(174, 199, 232);">Technology Internet</text><text text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(85,41)rotate(90)" style="font-size: 35px; font-family: Arial; fill: rgb(255, 127, 14);">Biology</text><text text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(-12,6)rotate(90)" style="font-size: 35px; font-family: Arial; fill: rgb(255, 187, 120);">Systems</text><text text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(-128,-93)rotate(0)" style="font-size: 34px; font-family: Arial; fill: rgb(44, 160, 44);">Movies</text><text text-anchor="middle" ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [XMLSerializer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XMLSerializer) to serialize the content to a string then create a [data uri](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) for the background image from that.

Comment: Thx! `Type Error: Failed to execute 'serializeToString' on 'XML Serializer'. Invalid node value` I updated the question with example output.

Comment: What code have you written that generates this error?

Comment: `var s = new XMLSerializer();
                        var d = $("#_wordcloud_element");
                        var str = s.serializeToString(d);`

Comment: I think you want d = $("#_wordcloud_element")[0]; as you can't pass a jquery object to the serializer you need to pass a raw DOM object.

Comment: Apologies for the late comment: I get 'invalid data url' - any ideas what could be wrong?: `url("data:<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='500' height='400'><g transform='translate(250,200)'><text text-anchor='middle' transform='translate(-113,88)rotate(0)' style='font-size: 19px; font-family: Arial; fill: rgb(31, 119, 180);'>Node.js</text></g></svg>")`

Comment: I see it: image/svg+xml;utf8,  - apologies, and thanks!